# SAS Create missing numeric ids into individual observations.

Tags: sas

I need to outline a series of ID numbers that are currently available based on a data set in which ID's are already assigned (if the ID is on the file then its in use...if its not on file, then its available for use).

The issue is I don't know how to create a data set that displays ID numbers which are between two ID #'s that are currently on file - Lets say I have the data set below -

```
data have;
input id;
datalines;
1
5
6
10
;
run;
```

What I need is for the new data set to be in the following structure of this data set -

```
data need;
input id;
datalines;
2
3
4
7
8
9
;
run;
```

I am not sure how I would produce the observations of ID #'s 2, 3 and 4 as these would be scenarios of "available ID's"...

My initial attempt was going to be subtracting the ID values from one observation to the next in order to find the difference, but I am stuck from there on how to use that value and add 1 to the observation before it...and it all became quite messy from there.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your set of possible IDs is know, this can be done by putting them all in a file and excluding the used ones.
e.g.

```
data id_set;
do id = 1 to 10;
    output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
create table need as
    select id
        from id_set
            where id not in (select id from have)
    ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary variable that stores the previous id, then just loop between that and the current id, outputting each iteration.

```
data have;
input id;
datalines;
1
5
6
10
;
run; 

data need (rename=(newid=id));
set have;
retain _lastid; /* keep previous id value */
if _n_>1 then do newid=_lastid+1 to id-1; /* fill in numbers between previous and current ids */
output;
end;
_lastid=id;
keep newid;
run;
```

Comment: I should have thought to retain...then count...good to have a functioning version of the concept. +1 for you...

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jetzler's answer: Another option is to use the MERGE statement. In this case:

> note: before merge, sort both datasets by id (if not already sorted);

```
data want;
    merge id_set (in=a)
          have (in=b); /*specify datasets and vars to allow the conditional below*/
    by id; /*merge key variable*/
    if a and not b; /*on output keep only records in ID_SET that are not in HAVE*/
run;
```